# Least amount of code to store data tuples in android

Tags: android, storage, android-room

In Android, what is the shortest/easiest way to just store a simple tuple of connected values, f.ex. `Date date`, `String name`, `int count`?

Using `SharedPreferences`, you could keep an incrementing ID and store the values as

```
editor = context.getSharedPreferences().edit();
editor.putString("name" + ID, name);
editor.putLong("date" + ID, date.getTime());
editor.putInt("count" + ID, count);
editor.apply();
ID += 1;
```

but the solution should scale to several thousands of entries. This is really about storing very simple data, so a DB like [Realm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42879394/1587329) might be overkill. [SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42879178/1587329) seems to require a lot of boilerplate.

Which approach requires the least programming effort/lines of code?

UPDATE: maybe [Android Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) would work?

Comment: SQLiteOpenHelper for only one table doesn't require much code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very basic `SQLiteOpenHelper` example, it has one table and can do select all and create a row

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static class Entry {
        public long id;
        public String value;
    }

    public static final int VERSION = 1;
    public static final String NAME = "MyDb";

    private static final String TABLE_ENTRY = "MyTable";
    private static final String KEY_ENTRY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_ENTRY_VALUE = "value";

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_ENTRY + "(" +
            KEY_ENTRY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            KEY_ENTRY_VALUE + " TEXT" +
            ")";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRY_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public List<Entry> selectAll(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ENTRY, null);
        List<Entry> output = new ArrayList<>();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                Entry entry = new Entry();
                entry.id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ENTRY_ID));
                entry.value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ENTRY_VALUE));
                output.add(entry);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    public long createEntry(Entry entry){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_ENTRY_VALUE, entry.value);

            return db.insert(TABLE_ENTRY, null, values);
        }catch (Exception e){
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for simple data as easiest ways you can create an Object class and put your values in that, then convert your class to JSON by using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), and save your JSON in SharedPreferences as a single value. then you can retrieve JSON from SharedPreferences and convert to your Object by using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

convert object to JSON:

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(yourModel);
```

convert JSON from String to Object:

```
YourObject myModel = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, YourObject.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [JDXA ORM](http://softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/jdxa.html) for Android to easily store object data in a SQLite database. It helps you avoid writing boilerplate code as shown below. Disclaimer: I am the architect of JDXA ORM.

JDXA is non-intrusive, flexible, and POJO-friendly. In this particular case, you may declare a POJO class SampleEntity as follows:

```
public class SampleEntity {
    private int id; // auto-generated by the database
    private String name;
    private Date date;
    private long count;

    /**
     * Default no-arg constructor needed for JDXA
     */
    public SampleEntity() {
    }

    public SampleEntity(String name, Date date, long count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.count = count;
    }

    // Other constructors and accessor methods omitted
```

The Object Relational Mapping (ORM) specification for this class can be defined declaratively as follows:

```
CLASS SampleEntity
    PRIMARY_KEY id
    SQLMAP FOR id SQLTYPE 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT'
    RDBMS_GENERATED id
;
```

The RDBMS_GENERATED specification above means that the values of the specified attributes (e.g., id) will automatically be generated by the underlying database.

JDXA provides simple APIs for CRUD operations. Here are some examples of such API calls (e.g., insert, query, delete):

```
JDXS jdxHandle = jxResource.getJDXHandle();

String sampleEntityClassName = SampleEntity.class.getName();

try {           
    // Delete all existing SampleEntity objects from the database.
    jdxHandle.delete2(sampleEntityClassName, null, JDXS.FLAG_DEEP);

    // Create and save some SampleEntity objects. id will be automatically generated by the database.
    SampleEntity entity = new SampleEntity("Name1", new Date(), 10);
    jdxHandle.insert(entity, 0, null);

    entity = new SampleEntity("Name2", new Date(), 20);
    jdxHandle.insert(entity, 0, null);

    // Retrieve all the SampleEntity objects. They will come initialized with the database generated id values.
    List queryResults = jdxHandle.query(sampleEntityClassName, null, JDXS.ALL, JDXS.FLAG_DEEP, null); 
    ...
 } catch (Exception ex) {
 ...
 }
```

You don't need to write and maintain any SQL code. Also, a lot of boilerplate code for data transfer is avoided. Further, JDXA will automatically generate the required database schema.